# I have problem with virtualbox with header 3.16.0-41-generic

Tags: kernel, virtualbox

I tried to fix this for many day until my linux break.
When I run command

```
/sbin/rcvboxdrv/ setup
```

It display error:

```
 Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 3.16.0-41-generic cannot be
 found. Please install the linux-headers-3.16.0-41-generic package, or
 use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message says, install the header files via

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.16.0-41-generic
```

for the missing header files

or better, for an automatic install if you get a new kernel in the future

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
```

Comment: Now I installed 3.19.0-30-generic instead, but have problem with cannot boot. and I already remove 3.16.0-41-generic.

How can I do? fixed 3.19 or try to install 3.16?

Comment: Take the second part of my answer. And please, to change the context during answering your question is a bad idea.

Comment: Now linux-header is newest version. I cannot install 3.16. And have problem cannot boot.

Comment: After running the command in the second part of my answer you can't boot?

Comment: No I installed 3.19 and remove 3.16 before you will answered me. Now I have new problem I see 3.19 not stable.

Sorry for not clear question. Now I have problem cannot boot with kernel 3.19.0-* Can you help me?

Comment: Yes, remove 3.19 and install `linux-generic`